# Understanding the Google Analytics real-time API 50,000 call limit per project

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I am trying to build an application using Google Analytics real-time API. So, I see this quota limit at 50,000/project. I am aware of 10,000/Google Analytics View limit. So, based on these values, my application can handle only 5 users/day.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Its 50,000 API calls per day to query your data, not for collecting data.

What is this 10,000 Google Analytics View limit you refer to?  It is not listed on the [GA quotas and limits page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/limits-quotas)

There is a [10million hits per month](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/limits-quotas) limit per web property, if you go over that then they ask you pay for GA360